# Creating update with NSIS

Tags: nsis

I create my setup`s with NSIS. Now i faced with updates. Is there examples of how to create nsis installer with this functionality:

- detect older version
- delete files
- set new files

Thanks in advance

*P.S.: Sory for my bad english*

Answer (score 1):

What about running uninstaller of old version (Execute uninstall.exe in target directory) and then installing new version?

I think it is the simplest way and there is no effort for you as each software (usually) has uninstaller.

Comment: You can detect previous version in registry. Execute uninstaller then push new installer version.